# How can I listen to a bluetooth server and store its emitted messages?

Tags: java, kotlin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have a device that will return a 6 digit integer when I send the string `cmdc` to it. Call this a 'count command'. I'm currently using BtChat to send and receive data from the device. The device is the server. My app will be the client.

[image]

This is the function I use to send the string to the server when I am paired:

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun sendData(socket: BluetoothSocket? , data : String) {

 val toSend = data.toByteArray()

 val outputStream = socket!!.outputStream
 outputStream.write(toSend)

 outputStream.flush()
 outputStream.close()

}
```

How would I go about receiving the integer after issuing the command from my own application instead of BtChat?

I have attempted to listen to the server using the following class:

```
class ServerConnectThread(mBTSocket: BluetoothSocket?) : Thread() {
    private var bTSocket: BluetoothSocket? = mBTSocket

    fun acceptConnect(bTAdapter: BluetoothAdapter, mUUID: UUID) {
        var temp: BluetoothServerSocket? = null
        try {
            temp = bTAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("Dual-SPP", mUUID)
            // TODO: What should I do with the server socket?
            // Loop on a background thread until an integer is discovered?
            // When I print 'temp' I get the following:
            // ServerSocket: Type: TYPE_RFCOMM Channel: -1

        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.d("SERVERCONNECT", "Could not get a BluetoothServerSocket:" + e.toString())
        }

        while (true) {
            try {
                bTSocket = temp!!.accept()

            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.d("SERVERCONNECT", "Could not accept an incoming connection.")
                break
            }

            if (bTSocket != null) {
                try {
                    temp.close()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    Log.d("SERVERCONNECT", "Could not close ServerSocket:" + e.toString())
                }

                break
            }
        }
    }

    fun closeConnect() {
        try {
            bTSocket!!.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.d("SERVERCONNECT", "Could not close connection:" + e.toString())
        }

    }

}
```

Where should I initiate this class? The server seems to "emit" the integer a few seconds after the command is issued. How can I capture the returned value and store it in my application?

I was thinking that I might connect to the server in a JobIntentService right after pairing but it's not working for me currently:

```
class BluetoothService : JobIntentService() {

    var bluetoothDevice: BluetoothDevice? = null

    internal val mHandler = Handler()

    override fun onHandleWork(intent: Intent) {
        // We have received work to do.  The system or framework is already
        // holding a wake lock for us at this point, so we can just go.
        Log.i("SimpleJobIntentService", "Executing work: $intent")

        bluetoothDevice = intent.extras!!.getParcelable("btdevice")

        Log.d("CONNECTED ", bluetoothDevice!!.name)

        val i = Intent(baseContext, MainActivity::class.java)
        i.putExtra("btdevice_connected", bluetoothDevice)
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        application.startActivity(i)

        val deviceName = bluetoothDevice!!.name
        //println(deviceName)
        val mUUID = bluetoothDevice!!.uuids[0].uuid
        //println(mUUID)

        ServerConnectThread().run {
            acceptConnect(BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(), deviceName, mUUID)
        }


    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        // toast("All work complete")
    }

    // Helper for showing tests
    internal fun toast(text: CharSequence) {
        mHandler.post { Toast.makeText(this@BluetoothService, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * Unique job ID for this service.
         */
        internal val JOB_ID = 1000

        /**
         * Convenience method for enqueuing work in to this service.
         */
        internal fun enqueueWork(context: Context, work: Intent, btdevicE_JOB_ID: Int) {
            JobIntentService.enqueueWork(context, BluetoothService::class.java, btdevicE_JOB_ID, work)
        }
    }
```